# Select first dash only with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to select the first dash `-` only and before the space?

`HEllo Good - That is my - first world`

The regex I wrote `.+?(?=-)` selected `HEllo Good - That is my`.

If I have only the string `HEllo Good - That is my`, it looks ok, but with the space.

```js
var string = 'HEllo Good - That is my - first world';
console.log(string.match(/.+?(?=-)/gm));
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Your title and your question ask different things ("everything before first dash" vs. "first dash only").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the **first dash only**, just match the string using the beginning of input `^`:

```js
const text = 'HEllo Good - That is my - first world';
const pattern = /^.*?\s(-)/;
const match = text.match(pattern);

console.log(`full match: ${match[0]}`);
console.log(`dash only: ${match[1]}`)
```

If you need **what's before**, including/excluding the first dash:

```js
const text = 'HEllo Good - That is my - first world';
const patternIncludeDash = /(^.*?\s-)/;
const patternExcludeDash = /(^.*?\s)-/;

console.log('before the dash, but include dash: ' + text.match(patternIncludeDash)[1]);
console.log('before the dash, but exclude dash: ' + text.match(patternExcludeDash)[1]);
```